# Finding elements in a set

Tags: combinatorics

**Definitions**
You have a set $S$ with $n$ elements. Within these $n$ elements, we denote $2$ as *"special numbers"*.
Given a subset $T\subset S_n$ we say that the subset $T$ is "*up*" if it contains both the special numbers, "*down*" if it contains none or just one of the two special numbers.

**Problem**
You're given a subset $A$ containing $n$ elements. You know the elements of $A$, but you don't know which are the two special numbers in it.
In order to find out the two special numbers, you can choose $k$ subsets $B_k\subset A$ and, after you've chosen them, know if those subset are up or down.
**What's the minimum value of $k$ in order to univocally identify the two special numbers?**

Comment: If the problem isn't clear, let me know and I'll add examples.

Comment: I can do it in $k={n\choose 2}$ tests, just take every pair of elements. :-)

Comment: I think it can be optimized to $2*log_2 n$ but I need a proof

Comment: Possibly for large $n$, but how do you beat my method for $n=4$?

Comment: @vadim123 For n=4 we take the subsets {1,2} {1,3} {2,4} {3,4}

Comment: We are to choose $k$ bit strings $b_i$ of length $n$ (representing subsets $B_k$ of $A$) and then run them through $f(x):=((x\wedge s)\ne 0)$ where $s$ contains only 2 that "special" bits set to so we can univocally identify the positions of the 2 bits as a function of $f(b_1),\dots ,f(b_k)$? Similar problem with only one special bit give the answer of $\lceil\log_2 n\rceil$. This case it should be $\lceil\log_2 {n\choose 2}\rceil$ I guess.

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin Good point, that is the problem. I know of the $log_2 n$ solution when you only have 1 bit to identify, I also know how to build the subsets in that case, but in this problem we have 2 bits to identify. Where did $log_2{n\choose2}$ come from?

Comment: @vadim123 Ah sorry, I wrongly wrote the sets. The sets are actually {1,2} {1,2,3} {2,3,4} {3,4}

Comment: Hm, the theory of information? You need at least k bits to univocally identify a number in range $1\dots 2^k$ where ${n\choose 2}$ is the number of pairs. Maybe I could show that $k=4$ is sufficient for $n=6$ while $2\log_2 n$ gives at least 5. Do I need to?

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin That would be appreciated. Post it as answer, of course!

Comment: Apparently they are 5: {{2,3,4,5,6},{1,3,4,5,6},{1,2,4,5,6},{1,2,3,5,6},{1,2,3,4,6}} for n=6... And a particular case __won't__ be an answer... :)

Comment: Here's some idea.  Let $k = k_{n,r}$ be the minimum number of sets $S_1, \ldots, S_k \subseteq S$ with $|S| = n$ and each $|S_i| = r$ so that every pair of elements of $S$ is contained in some $S_i$.  Once such a set has been found, there is guaranteed to be an $S_i$ that is "up", and then you can limit your search to only that $S_i$, and so on, recursively.  By optimizing your choice of $r$ you should be able to get a bound in terms of the numbers $k_{n,r}$.

Comment: To be clear, you'd need to find such a family $S_1, \ldots, S_k$; then for each $i$ choose another family of subsets $S_{i1}, S_{i2}, \ldots \subseteq S_i$ with the same property, and so on.  This method probably isn't the smartest, though, because it's disregarding some information at each stage.

Comment: I'm assuming you have to choose all your subsets at once instead of in steps based on the information you've gained.